# Using sqoop incremental update for updating Hive table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to update a hive table, based on the records from a mysql table.

```
mysql-table: (table name: delimiter_test)

+---------------+-----------------+
| department_id | department_name |
+---------------+-----------------+
|             2 | Fitness         |
|             3 | Footwear        |
|             4 | Apparel         |
|             5 | Golf            |
|             6 | Outdoors        |
|             7 | Fan Shop        |
|             8 | Test            |
+---------------+-----------------+

hive-table (table name: my_test)

2   Fitness
3   Footwear
4   Apparel
5   Golf
6   Outdoors
7   Fan Shop
```

I am trying to use sqoop, to import the last record in the mysql table with department_id 8, into hive table using incremental-update in sqoop.

my-sqoop command:

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" --username xxx --password xxx --table delimiter_test  --hive-import  --hive-table my_test  --split-by department_id  --check-column department_id --incremental append --last-value 7
```

I am not getting any errors,but the extra record from the mysql table with department_id 8 is not getting updated into the hive table.

Please suggest me where am I going wrong.

Comment: Command seems good to me. Can you add `--verbose` in the end of your swoop command to see extended logs and see if you find any errors?

Comment: @devツ I noticed something wierd, when I added the number of mapers to be 10 (--m 10), the extra record with department_id 8, was inserted twice in the hive table, and with --m 6, the record got inserted correctly.

Comment: Is department _id string in hive table ?  Share full logs after `--verbose`

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37389134/2700344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if probably we are working on itversity labs. Well I have done this thing using the code below. probably that could work for you too.

First load data in hive

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxx/retail_db --username xxxx --password xxxx \
--table departments --where department_id=2 --hive-import --hive-database poc --hive-table departments_sqoop  \
--target-dir /user/ingenieroandresangel/sqoop/dep_hive --split-by department_id -m 1
```

Then I perform the update with the script below:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx/retail_db --username xxxxx --password xxxx \
--table departments --where 'department_id>=2' --hive-import --hive-database poc --hive-table departments_sqoop  --incremental append \
--check-column department_id --last-value 2 --target-dir /user/ingenieroandresangel/sqoop/dep_hive --split-by department_id -m 1
```

Answer (score 0):

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx/mysql_db --username xxxxx --password xxxx 
--table departments  --target-dir /sqoop/dep_hive --hive-import --hive-database poc --hive-table departments_sqoop  --incremental lastmodified
--check-column department_id --last-value 2 -m 1

#when appending data directly to the hive table use tag --incremental lastmodified  (If appending to hdfs FILE you can use --incremental-append)

#to overwrite hive table you can add tag --hive-overwrite

#last-value will be excluded in file import.

Comment: I can't tell how this solves the questioner's problem. Could you add some explanation?