# Sqoop: Import with --split-by using sql function

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I am sorry if this has been answered earlier but i am not able to find it here on Stack Overflow.

My source Mysql tables are having PK as Varchar and while import it's brining in duplicates which is not good, I dont want to use -m 1 since the tables are around 50GB each so i am trying to give in the split by option on a column that i know is defined as varchar but its an INT like below

I am on sqoop 1.4.7 on EMR 5.14.0

```
sqoop import -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true \
--connect jdbc:mysql://host/jslice \
--username=*** --password *** --table orders --fields-terminated-by '|' \
--lines-terminated-by '\n' --null-non-string "\\\\N" --null-string 
"\\\\N" --escaped-by '\' \
--optionally-enclosed-by '\"' --map-column-java dwh_last_modified=String 
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--as-parquetfile -m 16 --compress --compression-codec 
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec --delete-target-dir \
--target-dir hdfs:///hive/warehouse/jslice/orders/text3/ --split-by 
'cast(order_number as UNSIGNED)'
```

Internally sqoop builds the boundary query as

```
INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT 
MIN(`cast(order_number as UNSIGNED)`), MAX(`cast(order_number as 
UNSIGNED)`) FROM `archive_orders`
```

and throws an error

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: 
java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=472029) 
Unknown column 'cast(order_number as UNSIGNED)' in 'field list'
```

I have seen posts that says we can pass in sql functions on the split-by but i want to make sure if it really works

Note I have tried with " " as well and the cast command with back ticks

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/146261/sql-function-in-split-by.html

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/Sqoop-split-by-date-wants-to-compare-a-timestamp-with/m-p/69668#M3159

Comment: What is strange here is backquotes in boundary query. They probably causing error. Try to provide --boundary-query parameter manually.

Comment: This backticks in boundary query causing database think it is column name. Maybe bug in your sqoop version. just provide  boundary-query parameter manually, without backticks.

Comment: No the Boundary query does work, but i figured that even though we do split by using a cast on a varchar column, once the split is identified sqoop internally does a sort of the Primary key column or the split-by column which if its a varchar on the Mysql datatype then and it brings in Duplicate on the target system. I believe this is bcoz if the mysql column are defined as case insensitive (which is true in my case)

I found unless you use a integer column or do an incremental load (after load to staging) will not solve the issues of duplicate on target with Varchar datatype on split-by